# QNX Object oriented threads in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, qnx

I want to create a parallel object oriented system in QNX using c++ and threads. How do I do this?

I tried:

```
pthread_t our_thread_id;
pthread_create(&our_thread_id, NULL, &functionA ,NULL);
```

with function A being a pointer to a function:

```
void *functionA()
{ //do something
}
```

However this function only works in C and not C++. How can I make it work in C++?

Answer (score 2):

See ["How do I pass a pointer-to-member-function to a signal handler, X event callback, system call that starts a thread/task, etc?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.2).

In short, you pass a static function (the "trampoline") as the function pointer. You pass "this" as the user-defined parameter. The static function then bounces the call back to the real object.

For example:

```
class Thread {
public:
    int Create()
    {
        return pthread_create(&m_id, NULL, start_routine_trampoline, this);
    }

protected:
    virtual void *start_routine() = 0;

private:
    static void *start_routine_trampoline(void *p)
    {
        Thread *pThis = (Thread *)p;
        return pThis->start_routine();
    }
};
```

And you need to ensure that the C++ function has the same calling convention as expected by pthread_create.

Answer (score 1):

Your `functionA` is not a pointer to a function, it's a function returning a `void*`. The function is also expected to take a void* as argument. This argument is used to pass a pointer to the data needed in the thread.

If you replace

```
void* functionA() {
```

with

```
void functionA(void* threadData) {
```

I'd expect it to work in both C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare `functionA` as being `extern "C"` (and give it the correct signature, see the [documentation for pthreads on QNX](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/lib_ref/p/pthread_create.html)). This function takes as user parameter the `this` intance:

```
extern "C"
{
   void* DoSomethingInAThread(void* pGenericThis)
   {
     YourClass* pThis = reinterpret_cast<YourClass*>(pGenericThis);
     pThis->DoSomethingInAThread();
   }
}

int main()
{
  YourClass* pSomeInstance = new YourClass();
  pthread_t our_thread_id;
  pthread_create(&our_thread_id, NULL, &DoSomethingInAThread, pSomeInstance);
}
```